# Proof or a counterexample of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have the following exercise, how can I proceed?

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, with $S \subset A$ and $f:A\to B$ a function, and $g:A\to B$ be an extension of $f\rvert_S$ to $A$. Does $g$ equal $f$? Give a proof or a counterexample

Comment: Note: If $S=\emptyset$, then every $g$ is an extension of $f|S$ to $A$.

Comment: How i can to proof it?

Answer (score 3):

I think what would really help is clarifying *exactly* what's going on with the problem.

When you have $f : A \to B$, then the restriction $f \rvert_S : S \to B$ just means you stop paying attention to where $f$ sends things in $A \setminus S$, but focus just on $S$.

So, when you write the statement $g : A \to B$ is an extension of $f\rvert_S$, that just means that

$$f(s) = g(s) \text{ for all }s \in S.$$

In other words, $f$ and $g$ *agree* on $S$. But if all you know is that $f$ and $g$ agree on a proper subset of their domain, why should they have to agree *anywhere* else, let alone *everywhere* else?

I'm confident you can find examples of functions that agree somewhere, but not everywhere.

Note: There are contexts in which agreement on a subset forces agreement on the full domain, but this requires additional, often strong, assumptions. For example, this is true when $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions that agree on a dense subset of a topological space, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is a set with a single element: yes. Without any requirements the extension has to fulfill, there will be many other ways to construct an extension.

Comment: An example can be of the type?